# Did I use class correctly?

Tags: php

I have two classes. Database and Product. I successfully connected PHP with DB and I am able to print out data. 
But I want to know if I am using class Product correctly? And if in future I add Product class method addProduct should I need to keep properties?

My Product class:

```
<?php
require_once 'DataBase.class.php';
class Product  {

    //Properties
   // var $id;
   // var $name;
   // var $price;


    //Methods
    function __construct(){}

    public function getAllProducts()
    {

        $db = Database::get();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
        $result = $db->select($sql);
        return $result;
    }       
}

$product = new Product;
```

Right now it seems that I don't need properties.

Comment: you can use properties without defining them in php classes, however, zend engine will optimize memory consumption if you define them, so yeah, you can skip defining them, but your code will be more messy and will need more memory

Comment: If you do use properties don't use the 'var' keyword for declaring them. This will work in some versions of PHP5 but has been deprecated and may not work at all in PHP7 (I'm not certain about that). You should use 'public', 'private' or 'protected' depending on the desired scope.

Comment: Consider making getAllProducts static - or maybe move it to other class - it not OOP...

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the `getAllProducts()` function from the individual products class. Like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'DataBase.class.php';

function getAllProducts()
{
    $db = Database::get();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
    $result = $db->select($sql);
    return $result;
} 

class Product  {

    // Properties:
    public $sku;
    public $name;
    public $price;
    public $size = '0';
    public $weight = '0';
    public $dimension = '0x0x0';

    // Methods
    function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3) // add or remove vars as needed
    {
        // use make a new product, example:
        $this->sku = $var1;
        $this->name = $var2;
        $this->price = $var3;
        // etc...
    }

}

$product = new Product($var1, $var2, $var3);
// do stuff with the product
```

Your constructor should deal with instantiating product information for use with your database. Also, PHP is notoriously terrible for its character escape techniques. Prepared statements and typecasting will make your life easier in the long run.